# Java integrated kettle connection hive exception, using Hadoop Hive2 in kettle, can connect but can not query

Tags: java, hive, kettle

Each database has its own `jdbc, hive-jdbc isSigned` and other methods are empty implementation, kettle `ValueMetaBase` source code `4360` lines

```
Boolean signed = rm.isSigned( index )
```

how does `kettle` solve the throwing exception?

In `kettle's` spoon debugging, you can connect to `hive` to run, but run `ktr` through Java, an exception occurs when running to the above code

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What type of object is `rm`? You need to look at its source code

Comment: rm is a ResultSetMetaData interface of sql in jdk, in the program it is the implementation of hive-jdbc on ResultSetMetaData interface

Comment: I added a picture in the question to indicate the value of rm when the program is running.

Comment: Debugging hive.ktr with Spoon is ok, but debugging with Java will prompt for exceptions. I suspect that some configuration is missing, but I don't know what it is. Can it help me analyze it?

Comment: I don't know what Spoon or KTR are, but the error seems to be this Pentaho driver just do not support the operations your are trying to run